# Misinformation in DataStage XML Export

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

As the title suggests, I am just trying to do a simple export of a datastage job. The issue occurs when we export the XML and begin examination. For some reason, the wrong information is being pulled from the job and placed in the XML.

As an example the SQL in a transform of the job may be:
SELECT V1,V2,V3 FROM TABLE_1;

Whereas the XML for the same transform may produce:
SELECT V1,Y6,Y9 FROM TABLE_1,TABLE_2;

It makes no sense to me how the export of a job could be different then the actual architecture.

The parameters I am using to export are:
Exclude Read Only Items: No
Include Dependent Items: Yes
Include Source Code with Routines: Yes
Include Source Code with Job Executable: Yes
Include Source Content with Data Quality Specifications: No

Comment: Import it and check if it is the original statement - if not open a PMR with IBM - if it is the same you are looking at the wrong place...

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher is there another place I should be looking? I just go to the job and select export. From there I use the parameters as above. I did import the job as the XML that was output and I can't find any differences in the job.

Comment: So this means the right SQL is in it ... somewhere...  What is the goal of your examination?

Comment: After some further examination it seems that the XML is more than likely corrupt by bad data connections and other configuration issues. For example, the table definition for one of the tables is in a folder that is no longer existent in the project. Not sure if possible to capture the most up to date XML file for the project.

Comment: Well you wrote that you got all you had after importing again - so it is not corrupt - it may hold old versions or anything IBM decided to go in there. If you insist that it is corrupt you can open a problem case with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to view the XML?  Try using something less smart, such as Notepad or Wordpad.  This will determine/eliminate whether the problem is with your XML viewer.
You might also try exporting in DSX format and examining that output, to see whether the same symptoms are visible there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback. I realized that the issue wasn't necessarily with the XML. It had to do with numerous factors within our data stage environment. As mentioned above, the data connections were old and unreliable. For some reason this does not impact our current production refresh, so it's a non issue.

The other issue was the way that the generated SQL and custom SQL options work when creating the XML. In my case, there were times when old code was kept in the system, but the option was switched from custom code to generate SQL based on columns. This lead to inconsistent output from my script. Thus the mini project was scrapped.